# C# library to clean up html

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I was wondering if there is a library in .Net to clean up and remove unclosed tags in an html document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlTidy!

See the url below for more details:

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20505/0/page/2

The source of the download/project is:

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

I gave the other link because it contains information about a .net wrapper and setting everything up. Hope this helps!

Comment: For C# the specific link is a project maintained by Mark Beaton, called TidyManaged https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged

Answer (score 3):

html agility pack

http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I've tried to use Html Agility Pack but was not successful, what I did is to create a new HtmlDocument passing the string containing the html I want to fix in the constructor, however, I need to return the document as string which I dont know how to do it

Comment: I parsed my text using the HtmlDocument class but it still leaves unclosed tags there, is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember, but try outputasxml, or there's another option on there to fix nested tags but I'm not sure under what circumstances it works.

Comment: Luke, I believe your referring to the answer I just gave to my own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175071/how-would-i-get-the-inputs-from-a-certain-form-with-htmlagility-pack-lang-c-ne

Comment: I wasn't, I've used it before, but that's a great post and thanks for sharing